# Can we have dictionaries as elements of a list, if so how do we call out a specific value of the of a specific dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I get the value of a dictionary inside a list?

```
my_dict1 = {'cars': 1 , 'lorries': 2}
my_dict2 = {'boys': 10, 'girls': 15}

my_list = [my_dict1, my_dict2]
```

Comment: `boys = sum([d.get("boys",0) for d in my_list])` - this gets the total amount of boys.

Comment: Thank you "Larry the Llama", that was lightning quick, and to the point!!!